# How to do a Boolean mask to multiple columns with the same value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that has 6 columns, Z, A, B, C, D, E. Also has multiple rows. I am interested in leaving in the DataFrame all the data except where in columns A through E are equal to 0 in the same row.

```
df = pd.read_excel('Energy.xls')
```

```
df
```

```
Z| A | B | C | D | E |
7| 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
8| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
5| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
6| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
```

and I want this:

```
Z| A | B | C | D | E |
7| 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
5| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
```

I  thought this would work:

```
list = ['A','B','C','D',E']
```

and then:

```
df = df[df['list'] != 0]
```

But it didn't work, can somebody help me solving this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is use `all` with `axis=1`:

```
df[(df[list] != 0).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   Z  A  B  C  D  E
0  7  1  2  2  3  3
2  5  1  2  3  4  5
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your proble is not a big deal. so here is my answer:

```
#df is your dataFrame
newDf = df[df["A"] != 0 & df["B"] & df["C"] & df["D"] !=0 & df["E"] != 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can count 0s on each row and if its less than 6 show that row:

```
df = df[lambda x: x.apply(lambda s: s.to_list()[1:].count(0)<5,axis=1)]
```